# Can't compare strings with symbols?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, compare

Why can't I compare a string with a string containing an operator?

My issue:

```
python
Python 3.7.2 (default, Jan 10 2019, 23:51:51)
[GCC 8.2.1 20181127] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> val = "<="
>>> val
'<='
>>> val is "<="
False
>>>
```

Edit #1: I just now realized `==` works, but why is this? Surely they should both return true?

Edit #2: I'm an idiot, thanks for the info!

Comment: Are you asking why `is` is returning false?

Comment: `is` is not `==`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure if i'm just not escaping these characters right but I wouldn't think I'd have to.

Comment: No. Don't use `is` for comparisons.

Comment: Long story short, `is` checks if they'll literally the same object. Two strings with the same value aren't necessarily the same string in memory.

Comment: Ah, I see now. I'm coming from C++ so the `is` operator is foreign to me, but I got it now. Thanks!